# ApiVersionNeutral causes {version} parameter to show in swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I've upgraded a project from .net core 3.1 to .net 8. I had to update packages from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Versioning to Asp.Versioning.Mvc.

I use versioning in my routes:

```
[ApiController]
[ApiVersionNeutral]
[ApiConventionType(typeof(DefaultApiConventions))]
[Route("~/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
   [HttpGet("{userId}", Name = "GetUser")]
   public async Task<ActionResult<UserResponseModel>> GetUser([FromRoute] int userId)
   {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

The versioning worked fine before the upgrade, but afterwards `{version}` is now a parameter (seen in Swagger)
`/v{version}/GetUser/{userId}`

If I change `[ApiVersionNeutral]` to [ApiVersion("1.0")] the endpoint is correct.
`/v1/GetUser/{userId}`

My config has, and always had, the correct options:

```
services.AddApiVersioning(c =>
{
   c.ReportApiVersions = true;
   c.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
   c.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
});
```

Any ides on why `[ApiVersionNeutral]` has this issue?

**RESOLVED!**

I found that I also need AddApiExplorer option `AddApiVersionParametersWhenVersionNeutral = true`

Comment: Hi @user1630508, it is better for you to share how do you implements the `[ApiVersionNeutral]`.

Comment: @user1630508 resolve by answering your question. [Answer my own Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.)